# Confused notation about generated subring, generated subfield and polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, notation

I'm studying J.S. Milne's Fields and Galois Theory and I can't understand his notation. (The book is freely consultable [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf))

Let $E \supseteq F$ an extension field; the book defines $F[S]$ as the smallest subring in $E$ containing the subset $S \subseteq E$ and $F(S)$ as the smallest subfield in $E$ containing the subset $S \subseteq E$.
So it's natural that if that ring $F[S]$ is also a field I can write $F[S]=F(S)$.

Then it defines $F[X]$ as the ring in the indeterminate X as the usual way (page 9). Note that I've used $X$, not $x$.

My problems start at page 15 in the paragraph "Construction of some extension fields". The paragraph ends with the conclusion that, given a monic irreducible polynomial $f(X) \in F[X]$ such that $\deg(f(X))=m$, $F[x] := \frac{F[X]}{(f(X))}$ is a field of degree $m$ over $F$.

I've understood (evidently not very well) the construction of this quotient ring but then the book says that he writes $x$ instead of the image $P(X) \in \frac{F[X]}{(f(X))}$ where $P: F[X] \to \frac{F[X]}{(f(X))}$ is the usual projection to the quotient ring. And then (as mentioned early) he say that $F[x] := \frac{F[X]}{(f(X))}$.

But what is this $F[x]$? Is it a polynomial ring over the indeterminate $x$? Why is used this notation? If it's a field why isn't written $F(x)$?

Comment: If you're writing this kind of math, then some LaTeX skills will probably be useful to you at some point, so the small corrections I made in your MathJax code should be worth understanding.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you very much, I understood well the corrections.

Comment: Just to be explicity: Note that in $a\deg f$ and $a\deg(f),$ coded as a\deg f and a\deg(f), there is spacing between $a$ and $\deg$ without any need to insert spacing manually, and the space to the right of $\deg$ depends on the context as a result of the way the software is written rather than of anything done by the user. $\qquad$

Comment: I knew you have a typo. Milne says " write $x$ for the image of $X$ in [...]". Actually, this very common when dealing with quotient rings of polynomial rings. I mean, if you have the ring $R[X]$ and some ideal $I$ of such ring, it's usual to write $x$ for the coset of $X$ mod $I$, i.e., $x=\overline{X}$.